# How to integrate this Bessel function of zero order second kind?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, bessel-functions

I am trying to solve  the following integral (eq. $(1)$) containing zero order Bessel function of the second kind but not getting it exactly.

$$P = \int_0^{y}K_0\left(\sqrt{\frac{x}{ab}}\right)\text{d}x \tag{1}$$

where $K_0(.)$ is zero order Bessel function of second kind, $a$ and $b$ are constants.

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Note: I am getting the answer using Mathematica. But I would like to solve it on my own.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: I am getting first order Bessel function of second kind after integration in Mathematica. But I am not getting how it is obtained....